# TimerOne Hanging

Tags: arduino-uno, library, timers

For the following program. Compiles and runs. I start the Serial Monitor (shown following code) and it asks me to input the Blink Rate. This runs in setup. Then it enters the loop and prints to the serial monitor the rate and starts the >Serial.println("the bl    And it hangs! I can exit the serial monitor and restart it and it does the same thing. So the program/sketch seems to be running fine but somehow the serial communication hangs?  Others have tried it and it works for them?  Using an Alien Aurora R5 running Win10 64bit Home.  Added some delays after another person tried it and it hung on them before adding delay and then ran for them.  They are using Win10 32bit and when tried on their 64bit laptop it hangs.

```
//Testing the Serial Port

#include <TimerOne.h>

int state = 0;
int value;
long int newtime;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, state);
  Serial.println("Enter the Blink Rate: ");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    value = Serial.parseInt();
    delay(100);
    Serial.print("the blink rate is: ");
    Serial.println(value);
    Serial.println("Enter a new blink rate: ");
    newtime = value * 1000000;
    Timer1.initialize(newtime);
    Timer1.attachInterrupt(blinkme);
    delay(500);
  }
}

void blinkme() {
  state = !state;
  digitalWrite(13, state);
  delay(100);
}
```

[image: Serial Monitor]

Comment: Why `delay(100);` when you already initialize the `Timer1` with the right blink time? Delaying in ISRs should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Delays were added after in attempt to get it to run.  Was advised by another that it hung for them UNTIL they added the delay at end of loop function.

Comment: Never ever use a delay in an interrupt

Comment: It hangs without any interrupts.

Comment: Please change `int state = 0;` to `volatile int state = 0;` and remove *all* `delay()` calls. Before `Timer1.initialize(...)`, add the line `Serial.flush();`. Does it work once now but not repeatedly?

Comment: If it is the case then the ISR crashes the board. `digitalWrite()` may disable interrupts.. better use direct port manipulation. Exchange the `digitalWrite` call with `DDRB ^= B00100000;`

Comment: Did the first comment and got a couple more lines in the monitor before it returned a 0 and hung.  DDRB ^= B00100000;  compiled but did nothing different.

Comment: Try using `unsigned long` as the type for both `value` and `newtime` (instead of `int` and `long int`). And use `1000000UL` instead of `1000000`.

Comment: Do you have anything connected to D13 that could cause a momentary fault like a short-circuit? If you have an external LED connected you also have the current limiting resistor right?

Comment: No change...  still hangs

Comment: I have tried it with both an LED and current limiting resistor on D13 and with nothing attached to D13 other than the onboard internal LED.

Comment: I have tried multiple versions of UNO and MEGA boards.  I don't think it is board related.  I have also tried a new TimerOne library from GitHub with the same results.

Comment: test value for 0 and don't set the timer with 0

Comment: Use `1000000L` instead of `1000000`

Comment: 0 hangs after the 3rd line on the monitor so it really doesn't like 0 for an input.

Comment: No Joy w/ 1000000L

Answer (score 3):

If you enter 1 in Serial Monitor and you have line ends selected, the Serial Monitor sends "1\r\n". parseInt() reads 1 and in next loop \r or \n is available and parses as 0. You then set the Timer to 0. The Serial can't finish printing because the Timer fires without a pause.

Comment: BINGO!  Changed the monitor to no line end and now works fine!  Thanks!

Comment: @SamR, accept he answer to mark it solved

Comment: @SamR, `Changed the monitor to no line end` ... that is not the way to correct the problem ... instead, insert code that prevents `newtime` from being zero

Answer (score 0):

Change io 13 to (suggestion) 10 and attach led + 1k resister to io 10. 
13 seems to be in use. Also No line end in Serial.